# How to create a grid of 10degx10deg polygons for a shapefile using GDAL

Tags: python, gdal

I want to create a shapefile using the GDAL library. And I want this Shapefile, when created, to have a grid of square polygons. And where each polygon cell is 10 degrees by 10 degrees, ultimately I want this grid to cover the entire world. As well, I also want the shapefile to contain a decimal column 'LAND', which should be populated with 0.0 for all rows/cells.

Having confusion here because I've never used GDAL before and just sifting through the documents is confusing me. I think I understand how to create a shapefile something like the following:

```
from osgeo import ogr
from osgeo import osr
import gdal

# specifying that I want to work with a shapefile
DriverName = 'My Shapefile'
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName(DriverName)


Filename = 'points.shp'
```

---

Just a little lost here. Not sure exactly how this would be done through GDAL.
I know if I am creating the world, the extent of the world is -180 deg to 180 deg longitude and -90 deg to 90 deg for latitude. And that I should create a nested loop somewhere to loop the outer of longitudes and the inner of latitudes, stepping a value of 10 each time for spatial resolution for the grid.

It's just the whole-set up and the library functionally is confusing not sure what way to go about all this.

---

The general structure of the code I'd think would be something like:
- Import GDAL and other modules
- create a spatial reference
- Create an empty shapefile
- create a layer in the shapefile and assign it the spatial reference
- create a set of point geometries as a ring
- add those point geometries in an order to a polygon geometry
- create a feature and add the polygon Geometry to it
- put the feature in the layer

---

I examine the GDAL library website and found this:
link: https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/

and then more specifically a section that said "Create a New Shapefile and Add Data"
link: https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html#create-a-new-shapefile-and-add-data

---

I looked at the following but they did not help so much:
link: [Creating square grid polygon shapefile with Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54119/creating-square-grid-polygon-shapefile-with-python/81120)

and

link: [Creating grid polygons from coordinates using R or Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/97462/creating-grid-polygons-from-coordinates-using-r-or-python)

I am trying to piece all this information together in order to solve my task but it is proving difficult.

Please help how would I create a shapefile being a grid of 10x10degree polygons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it (in R):

```
xmin <- -180
ymin <- -90
side <- 10 # degrees of the side of each cell
listP <- list() # creates an empty list (which is similar to an array)
lands <- vector() # creates an empty array
k <- 1
nx <- 36 # number of cols
ny <- 18 # number of rows
for (i in 1:nx) { # for each col
  x1 <- xmin + (i-1)*side
  x2 <- xmin + i*side
  print(paste(i,"/",nx,sep="")) # just in case it takes too long
  flush.console() # same above
  for (j in 1:ny) { # for each row
    y1 <- ymin + (j-1)*side
    y2 <- ymin + j*side
    p = Polygon(cbind(c(x1,x1,x2,x2,x1),c(y1,y2,y2,y1,y1)))
    pP = Polygons(list(p), as.character(k))
    listP[[length(listP)+1]] <- pP # append to the array
    lands[length(lands)+1] <- 0 # append to the array
    k <- k+1
  }
}
Grid <- SpatialPolygons(listP, 1:(k-1))
d <- data.frame(LAND=lands)
spdf <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(Grid, data=d)
```

Looks like the code in Java you showed should be something like:

```
form osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import ogr
from osgeo import osr
import os
import random

# Specify that you want to work with a Shapefile
DriverName = "ESRI Shapefile"
# Not sure what this line does
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName(DriverName)

# Name of shapefile to create
FileName = 'gride.shp'

# simple check to see if that file already exists in the system, if so delete it
if os.path.exists(FileName):
  driver.DeleteDataSource(FileName)

# Now create an Empty shapefile Data source
shapeData = driver.CreateDataSource(FileName)

fieldName = 'LAND'

lng_min = -180
lng_max = 180
step = 10

lat_min = -90
lng_max = 90

poly = org.Geometry(ogr.wkbPolygon)
for lng_var in range(lng_min, lng_max, step):
    for lat_var in range(lat_min, lat_max, step):
            ring = org.Geometry(ogr.wkbLinearRing)
            ring.AddPoint(lng_var, lat_var)
            ring.AddPoint(lng_var + step, lat_var)
            ring.AddPoint(lng_var + step, lat_var + step)
            ring.AddPoint(lng_var, lat_var + step)
            ring.AddPoint(lng_var, lat_var)
            poly.AddGeometry(ring)
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain a bit what is happening here? How would a 10deg x 10deg polygons be forged from this script? Should this be at some point outputting a final shapefile. I should to be able to open it up on QGIS.

Comment: What are the <- doing exactly, sorry if that's a dumb question. Could I use '=' instead?

Comment: @Ki_ They are almost the same, but = is more used in narrower scopes, like in function parameters. I don't know the exact difference, thus I always use `<-`, except in function definitions. And no, it's not a dumb question at all.

Comment: @Ki_ The loop is creating an array of `Polygons` (listaP) composed of one or more `Polygon` (p) (one, in this case), that will later be assembled together in the last 3 functions. If you look at the `slotNames` of any shapfile, you'll get closer to understand how they work.

Comment: I am not sure what tweaks to make here I will show what it should output, these were the directions: https://imgur.com/a/nv3n8Kr

Comment: Thanks. But I don't think I am suppose to use vector() or flush.console() I've never seen these before.

Comment: Also is this in Java? I am using python

Comment: @Ki_ Right, I corrected it and it works perfectly now, but it's in R (sorry). Probably you can apply the same logic (after all, R's `rgdal` is derived from the same GDAL you're using).

Comment: @Ki_ `vector()` creates an empty array, `flush.console()` is just to ensure the print of the previous message (to flush it to the console, instead of wait for the end of the loop).

Comment: My teacher gave some example code but I am not sure how to edit it to get it to do what it's suppose to do, here that is: https://codeshare.io/24p4M4

Comment: Also my teacher said I should use a code like this (not sure what he means by define ring and add two more lines to create the polygon):https://codeshare.io/GbLR8w

Comment: Now I am wondering what lng_var would be in that for loop.

Comment: @Ki_ I couldn't find "ring" or "lng_var" in that code. But I see it's very different from what you want. Can't you debug it and see what's happening?

Comment: I think my teacher was going off something else. He was using that to show how to create a shape file and I guess be able to export it to the desktop and launch it on QQIS? Not sure. Here is the code he gave directly for this project: https://codeshare.io/GbLR8w

Comment: I figured out what ring was suppose to be, I think ring = org.Geometry(org.wkbLinearRing), but the lng_var in that for loop not sure of, also imagine when I create the inner loop there will have to be a lat_var iterating.

Comment: Not sure how to complete the polygon that's why there is two ring.AddPoint()'s that are blank

Comment: Ok maybe lng_var and lat_var are just placeholders that don't iterate though anything. like 'i' or 'j', although not sure why it would be inside the AddPoint() there may be more to that.

Comment: @Ki_ I modified the code. See my answer. I think this should work now. You should create only one polygon (`poly = org.Geometry(ogr.wkbPolygon)` only once, before the two loops), and create/add rings only in the inner for.

Comment: Thank you. There was a few edits I made to it here (in python not java for anyone that uses the code later): https://codeshare.io/GbLR8w

Comment: Also, everything runs but nothing is being exported? I keep expected a file or something to pop up on my desktop after the code runs.

Comment: @Ki_ There's no command to export there. You have `poly`, which is a `org.Geometry(ogr.wkbPolygon)`. Now you need to look how to save it to a file. That will probably be a single command.

Comment: I think I have it set up but, still haven't been able to figure out how to add that part where I need to add a field that contains a decimal column called 'LAND', which should be populated with 0.0 for all rows/cells.

Comment: Here is where I am at in the code: https://codeshare.io/G8zLwE

Comment: Keep getting the error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'CreateLayer'

Comment: I don't know how to do that either. But after you save it to a shapefile, maybe it's easier to add that column in QGIS?

Comment: I read that when it's saying no attribute 'CreateLayer' that means it's not reading the layers correctly, is there any errors here: https://codeshare.io/G8zLwE

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76610/discussion-on-answer-by-rodrigo-how-to-create-a-grid-of-10degx10deg-polygons-for).