# Grid polygon generation by converting meter to degree using Python

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas, vector-grid, python-3

When given a shapefile as below as an Input, I would like to generate a 100x100 meter polygon grid using python.

I went through  [Creating a regular polygon grid over a spatial extent, rotated by a given angle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51282724) and  [Creating grid polygons from coordinates using R or Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/97462) but still am not able to achieve the end result.

Based on [Creating polygon grid using Geopandas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/269243/creating-polygon-grid-using-geopandas) my code is as below (similar to the post), grids are not created within polygon extent but is created somewhere outside.

Which part have I made a mistake?

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import numpy as np
poly = gpd.read_file('point.shp')
xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax = poly.total_bounds
print(xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax)
#-118.77194444444446 38.61038888888889 -118.66961111111112 38.78205555555555
length = 100
wide = 100
cols = list(range(int(np.floor(xmin)), int(np.ceil(xmax)), wide))
rows = list(range(int(np.floor(ymin)), int(np.ceil(ymax)), length))
rows.reverse()
polygons = []
for x in cols:
    for y in rows:
        polygons.append( Polygon([(x,y), (x+wide, y), (x+wide, y-length), (x, y-length)]) )

grid = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry':polygons})
grid.to_file('grid.shp')
```

[image: shpfile]
[image: result Grid]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use Geopandas, it is self explanatory in the answer below:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/316460/111567

Edit:
You are using WGS84 with Lat Lon, so width and height must be in degrees. 
Right now 100 x 100 means 100 degrees, that is why it is one polygon

Change that to roughly 0.001 (110 km * 0.001 is circa 100 m) for lat (length/Y direction) and wide to 0.00125 (80 km * 0.00125 is circa 100 m) for lon (width/X direction)

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import numpy as np
poly = gpd.read_file('point.shp')
xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax = poly.total_bounds
print(xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax)
#-118.77194444444446 38.61038888888889 -118.66961111111112 38.78205555555555
length = 0.001 ##### here
wide = 0.00125 ##### here
cols = list(range(int(np.floor(xmin)), int(np.ceil(xmax)), wide))
rows = list(range(int(np.floor(ymin)), int(np.ceil(ymax)), length))
rows.reverse()
polygons = []
for x in cols:
    for y in rows:
        polygons.append( Polygon([(x,y), (x+wide, y), (x+wide, y-length), (x, y-length)]) )

grid = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry':polygons})
grid.to_file('grid.shp')
```

Why those numbers? Check for more information about conversion of Lat/Lon to meters:
https://www.thoughtco.com/degree-of-latitude-and-longitude-distance-4070616

Comment: I made use of the code by I end up getting a single polygon , I have attached the images in the questions above.

Comment: @roshualine added edit, you are using geographic coordinate system, so it is in degrees (width and height) change it to equal units

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake. I was unaware of the conversion part, the link was helpful.